# How does Apple Silicon Chip support Intel based JDK-8 without rosetta?

Tags: java, java-8, x86, arm, apple-silicon

I am able to run zulu8.62.0.19-ca-jdk8.0.332-macosx_x64 on my M1Pro(arm64) Mac machine and run Casssandra. How is this possible without Rosetta ?

Comment: There are other x86-64 emulators, for example QEMU.  But last I read, QEMU ignores memory-ordering differences between AArch64 and x86-64, so it's only safe for single-threaded code.  Or maybe locks work, but acq/rel atomics might not actually be guaranteed, and might work like relaxed when run on AArch64, unless QEMU knows how to enable M1's strong memory-ordering mode.  For Java, if you don't want to let MacOS use Rosetta transparently, it would make much more sense to just use a native AArch64 JVM.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: The other interpretation is that they currently have it running on normal MacOS, which transparently uses Rosetta.  And they want to know how it could be possible without Rosetta.  I was trying to cover both interpretations, by mentioning that MacOS does use Rosetta transparently.  (Sahil: You can check in the process manage / resource monitor app, whatever it's called, with a column that shows if a process is x86 or ARM.)

Answer (score 0):

JDK compiles java code into java bytecode, which can be run on a JVM. Cassandra is developed in Java so it's essentially a bunch of java bytecode. Zulu provides JDK/JVM native to Apple Silicon and it has no issues running java bytecode as all JVMs do. This is a key strength of Java.

Comment: So zulu8.62.0.19-ca-jdk8.0.332-macosx_**x64** will actually run ARM64 executables?  Or are you suggesting they didn't actually install or run what they think they did?  The question is about a specific x86-64 JDK install, not how Java can run at all.